# How to use workbox to cache CDN assets without CORS support

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I wanted to use workbox for caching my assets through service worker. And I am using `workbox-webpack-plugin`'s InjectManifest to pre-cache the assets. It works fine while using it locally on dev.

The problem is, on production the assets are on CDN. I used the `modifyURLPrefix` option to rewrite the JS asset url to CDN, nice!
The problem I am facing is, the CDN does not support CORS and workbox makes all the requests using CORS. After going through the docs over and over, I tried using a custom fetch plugin

```
const customFetchPlugin = {
    requestWillFetch: ({ request }) => new Request(request, {
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
};
```

and then used in the routing

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        /(https:\/\/example\.com\/).*\.(js|css)/,
        new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
            cacheName: '3rd-cache',
            plugins: [
                new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
                    statuses: [0, 200]
                }),
                customFetchPlugin
            ]
        })
    );
```

This looks good to me, and I assumed it should not run into anymore CORS errors, but I am still getting CORS errors

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/xxx.js' from origin 'https://myexample.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

At this moment, I have run out of ideas. Please let me know what might I be doing wrong to make this work ? Thanks.

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors'` isn't going to help, it doesn't look like an opaque result will suit your needs.

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to cache CDN assets anyway... Why not let the client side caching do its work and save bandwidth?

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey The benefit of service worker here is that it can deliver the asset from the cache, and also fetch the new asset in background for next use. An example: suppose I have an asset which doesn't have long caching (which is valid when you want some kind of evergreen url). The client side caching would not help, and its supposedly not supposed to be cached as well. But with service worker you could cache it, and deliver it right from the bat for next request, so you don't wait for the resource to download, and it also updates the asset in background for next use. Awesome!!

Comment: @Quentin good question, but my problem here is that I am still running in to CORS issue even with using `mode: no-cors`. I know opaque request might be an issue, but you can assume the CDN I am using is pretty reliable and I would always get the asset delivered (unless I am using a wrong asset path).

Comment: @Sumit — It doesn't really matter if you get an asset delivered - if you tell JS not to use CORS then you won't have access to the data in the response. All it does is suppress the error message. (Why it doesn't suppress the error message I have no idea, but it sounds like trying to figure that out would be a waste of time(.